# What is the difference between buying stock in Shares VS Dollars?

Tags: investing, stock-markets, shares, usd-us-dollar, robinhood

I'm a newbie in the stock market, well in "RH" & "WB". I just received notice I can buy "some" Stock in **$ dollars** also, my question is: **What is the difference in buying stock in SHARES or in DOLLARS**, and what are the **PROS** & **CONS** of both?
All advice much appreciated, **Gracias, Thanks in advance**. **BTW this is my **1st question... :)**

Comment: Welcome to Stack.  Since I use neither Robinhood or WealthBuilder, I can only guess that they are offering you the ability to buy indicate a dollar amount of your puchase and then they will buy whatever number of shares required to invest that dollar amount

Comment: What do you mean by *"RH" & "WB"*? Who sent you this notice?

Comment: If a share costs $30 then what's the difference between buying $30 and buying 30 shares?

Comment: If share price is $30 then buying 30 shares cost you $900.  If share price is $30 and you buy $30 worth of shares then you buy one share.

Answer (score 4):

It is two slightly different ways of specifying how much you want to buy when placing a *market order* (i.e. one that is satisfied at whatever the current price is).

*For simplicity, I'm assuming there's no commission or other costs associated with dealing.*

Suppose you were interested in a stock that is currently priced at $30 (offer price), and you've got "around" $500 you want to invest. You could *either*:

- Place an order for 16 shares (= $500 / $30, in whole numbers<sup>**1**</sup>), *or*:
- Place an order for (up to) $500 worth of shares.

If you do so *fairly quickly* after seeing the $30 price-quote, and the price of the shares *hasn't changed much*, both will achieve essentially the same thing.

However, if the price of the shares *does* change significantly before your order is executed, the outcome will be different in each case:

- If you ordered 16 shares, you will *still* get 16 shares<sup>**2**</sup>, but they might cost noticeable more or less than $500. If the price rose to $35, they would cost $560; if it dropped to $25, they would cost $400.
- If you ordered (up to) $500 worth of shares, you will *still* get (roughly) $500 worth, but you may get more or less than 16 shares<sup>**1**</sup>. As before, if the price rose to $35, you would get 14 shares (costing $490); if the price dropped to $25, you would get 20 shares.

The main danger of ordering by number of shares if that it could cost considerably more than you were intending to spend.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> As [base64](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/24920/base64) pointed out in a comment, [*Robbinhood* offer *fractional shares*](https://robinhood.com/us/en/support/articles/fractional-shares/). Fundamentally I don't believe this alters the answer: it has no effect when specifying the number of shares to buy (other than you can buy in factions of a share), and only a minor effect when specifying the maximum to spend. At $30/share, $500 would get you 16.67 shares (to 2dp, although they can track down to a millionth of a share). At $35/share, you'd get 14.28 shares. You would also be *consistently* spending $500 (instead of only $490 if you got 14 shares at $35).

<sup>**1**</sup> Depending on the balance in your account, and the terms and conditions of your broker, it's *possible* that you may not get all 16 shares if the price rose too far.

Comment: Robinhood offers fractional shares https://robinhood.com/us/en/support/articles/fractional-shares/

Comment: @base64 Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I've added a note, though I don't believe it fundamentally changes anything.

Comment: The option to buy stock in dollars rather than shares is a feature of fractional shares. That's a minor difference unless you want to buy amazon with $500

Comment: @xyious I'd disagree. The platform I've used in the past didn't do fractional shares, but **did** allow you to specify either the number of shares, or the amount you wanted to spend.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't mention, was mostly regarding the first comment. Also I think Robinhood ripped me off because I bought shares with $5.56 and in my history I bought shares worth $5.28 ....